# Como evitar duplicado conjunto de campos en Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

tengo una clase

```
public class ZoneCoordinationGroup {


private String zone;
private String coordinationGroup;
private Integer order;
```

}
que extiende de otra que tiene el id, pero no puedo tener dos valores iguales de zone y order o de zone y coodinationGroup

por ejemplo puede haber un datos que sea

{
zone:1,
coordinationGroup:1
order:1
},
{
zone:1,
coordinationGroup:2
order:2
},
{
zone:2,
coordinationGroup:1
order:1
}

pero no
{
zone:1,
coordinationGroup:1
order:1
},
{
zone:1,
coordinationGroup:2
order:1
}
ni tampoco
{
zone:1,
coordinationGroup:1
order:1
},
{
zone:1,
coordinationGroup:1
order:2
}

Como puedo hacer esto en mongo sin necesidad de tener que te hacerlo programado y consultando a base de datos cada vez que vaya ha insertar un campo
Gracias

Comment: Hola que es lo que trataste para resolver esto, donde ocurre el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione con

```
@CompoundIndexes({
@CompoundIndex(name="zone__groups_index", def = "{'coordinationGroup' : 1, 'zone' : 1}",unique = true),
@CompoundIndex(name="zone_order_index", def = "{'zone' : 1, 'order' : 1}", unique = true)
```

})

gracias